# Actualizar variables PHP cuando se recarga la pagina

Tags: php

soy nuevo en esto y estoy aprendiendo, pero tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar.

Tengo una variable llamada $result donde recoge toda la informacion de la base de datos cuando te logueas, pero necesito que esta se actualice cada vez que se actualiza o accede a una pagina de la web.

La forma en que lo tengo es la siguiente:

- Accion del boton de login:

```html
<form class="nav-login-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

- Paginas de la web:

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
 
 include 'php/login.php';
    
 }
?>
```

- Archivo login.php

```html
include 'MySQL-conn.php'; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
 die("Conexion fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$NickEmail = $_POST['nick-email']; 
$Password = $_POST['password'];

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Nick, Email, Password, Rank, Coins FROM accounts WHERE Nick = '$NickEmail' OR Email = '$NickEmail'")) {
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 $hash = $row['Password'];

 if (password_verify($_POST['password'] , $hash)) {
  
  $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
  $_SESSION['Nick'] = $row['Nick'];
  $_SESSION['Email'] = $row['Email'];
  $_SESSION['Rank'] = $row['Rank'];
  $_SESSION['Coins'] = $row['Coins'];
  $_SESSION['start'] = time();
  $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60);      
  
  echo "<style>div.successful-login {display: inline;}</style>";
```

A partir de este codigo cuando te logueas, quiero hacer un codigo para el reload de la variable $result y a la vez que sobreescriba la variable $_SESSION.

El codigo del boton esta en todas las paginas debido a que tengo un formulario de login en el nav de cada pagina, por ello los 2 primeros codigos estan en todas las paginas.
Y el codigo del archivo login.php es ese, unicamente la parte donde lee la base de datos MySQL que es a lo que necesito que se le haga reload, a $result.

Alguna solucion? Sea lo que sea.

Comment: Deberías de pasar por este proceso cada vez que la página se recargue.

Comment: Añade esa parte del código a la pregunta para verlo todo porque no queda muy claro.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia ya actualice el post con lo que tengo, espero que lo entiendas